# M2Eclipse & Helios - errors

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I downloaded the latest Eclipse Helios Java EE package and installed it with success.
Now I want to install m2eclipse and I used the update site http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e (see here: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html)

An error occurs:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.archetype_common,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.dependency_tree,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.xml,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.jdt,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.launching,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven_embedder,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven_model_edit,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.nexus_indexer,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.pr,0.10.2.20100623-1649
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring,0.10.2.20100623-1649
```

The other way I found here: 
http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/install-sect-marketplace.html
is to use the new Eclipse Marketplace. I searched for m2eclipse, but there is no install button only "learn more".

What's wrong? How can I install m2eclipse with Helios?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I took the latest nightly build bia the update site and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/0.10.2.20100623-1649/
instead of: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

Comment: Yes, I used the latest nightly build, and then it worked for me.